# Passing ThisScriptsDirectory as a Parameter into Powershell from Batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, parameters

I've looked around a few different solutions on the topic of passing parameters into Powershell scripts using a batch file; however none of them quite worked for me. My batch is a little bit more complicated than the other questions I saw posted, and after much searching, I decided to post my own.

Here is my current batch file (which runs, but doesn't pass in a parameter):

```
@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%TrentsAdobeTool1.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& {Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList '-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ""%PowerShellScriptPath%""' -Verb RunAs"};
pause
```

I am trying to pass in ThisScriptsDirectory as a parameter to the script mentioned, store it, and be able to use it as a path (with additional folders added to the path later)

So, I'm wondering how I would need to change the batch file, and how I would accept the parameter into the Powershell script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to access the value of an environment variable, you can do this within your Powershell script via the PSDrive for environment variables.

Examples based on your batch file.

```
$ENV:ThisScriptsDirectory
$ENV:PowerShellScriptPath
```

Comment: This was perfect. Thank you!

Comment: So this was working for me initially, but I went back to make the script more robust and now any time I try to use $ENV:ThisScriptsDirectory it returns empty. Any reason why this would be?